# Java toArray() method: primitive result type

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am trying to do the following:

```
double[][] ret = new double[res.size()][columnSize];
for(int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++){
     ret[i] = res.get(i).toArray(new double[columnSize]);
}
```

where res is declared as `List<List<Double>>`. The above does not work because toArray() method wants a parametrized array to infer resulting type and that cannot be primitive...

Now, I could just change return type of my method to `Double[][]` but later on I have other functions from different APIs that expect `double[][]` 9primitives). That means there would be a lot of Upcasting, doesn't it?

ANy solutions, advices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot keep primitives in collections and you need to convert collections to array of primive types like this:

```
double[] toArray(Collection<Double> collection) {
    double[] arr = new double[collection.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Double d : collection) {
        arr[i++] = d;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: That was quite and easy solution... But not as nice :)

Comment: Unfortunately, no nicer solution is available.

Comment: Wow, it's unbelievable that Java *still* doesn't have array auto-unboxing. BTW this answer is for a single dimension. The question is for 2D array, so it requires nested for loops. Crazy for something so simple.

Answer (score 2):

With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com): [`double[] Doubles.toArray(Collection<? extends Number)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release12/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29) does the trick.

Comment: Wow, this is really useful mate! Just looked at it briefly and at first glance it seems like a library that makes up for java's mistakes and missing implementation. Anything similar you might know about btw?

Comment: I work on Guava.  If you're curious about all the things Guava offers, the best place to start is [the wiki](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained?tm=6).

Comment: Yeah looks good. Do you reckon this is the most complex suite ou there available?

Comment: Um.  Not sure what you mean, but not using Guava would be like having a hand tied behind my back.

Comment: I was wondering if there are similar packages, perhaps targetting other issues with Java as well, I should know about

Comment: @Bober02: the [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/) project has many sub-projects of varying utility.  commons-lang, commons-codec, and commons-configuration are three of my favorites.

Answer (score 0):

For 2D arrays.

```
private static int[][] convertListArray(ArrayList<Integer[]> al) {
    int[][] ret = new int[al.size()][];
    for (int i=0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        Integer[] row = al.get(i);
        ret[i] = new int[row.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            ret[i][j] = row[j];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```